# Having hard time removing this white background from a logo, need help

Tags: adobe-photoshop, selections, background-removal

I need to remove white background from this logo, but whatever I have tried, doesn't seem to work correctly. For example, when I try to use the magic eraser tool, it also erases some of the text. [image]

Comment: there are so many duplicates for this question... [have a look here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=remove+background+%5Bphotoshop%5D)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pen tool tat would be easier or else decrease the tolerance value in magic wand tool and try it you would get it perfectly. Check the below image i have tried with magic wand 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the logo color is contrast to the background, use Quick selection tool to select the pink logo. Now go to Select -> Inverse Selection. Press Delete. This makes the work much easier.

Answer (score -1):

You can duplicate the layer and remove the background by using pen tool.